# Bash. How to check one value contain in other value?

Tags: bash

The Questions is that:

> Create an "If-Else" condition in the "For"-Loop that checks if the
> variable named "var" contains the contents of the variable named
> "value". Additionally, the variable "var" must contain more than
> 113,469 characters. If these conditions are met, the script must then
> print the last 20 characters of the variable "var". Submit these last
> 20 characters as the answer.

```
#!/bin/bash
        
var="8dm7KsjU28B7v621Jls"         
value="ERmFRMVZ0U2paTlJYTkxDZz09Cg"
    
for i in {1..40}    
do    

        var=$(echo $var | base64)
            
    #<---- If condition here:

done
```

Comment: With what part of the question you have problem? What you have tried so far and why it did not  work?

Answer (score 0):

Set exit code 0 if v1 is substring of v2:

```
[[ $v2 == *$v1* ]]
```

Set exit code 0 if length of v3 is longer than v4:

```
(( ${#v3} > v4 ))
```

Get the last v5 characters of v6:

```
if [[ $v6 =~ (.{$v5})$ ]]
then
  v6_tail=${BASH_REMATCH[0]}
fi
```

Comment: Somehow I fail to see the relation to the specification in the question.

Comment: The OP wanted to know if one variable contains the value of another variable, whether one variable is longer than a certain size, and what are the last n characters of a variable. I provided an answer to each of these questions, because with this, it becomes trivial to write the program the OP wants ot achieve.